# Swift unable to add tab bar to tab bar view controller? Grayed out?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Ok, my experience with tab bar controllers is limited but Ive never encountered this issue. I am able to create a tab bar controller but not add a tab bar or tab bar item tp it. I have followed this : https://makeapppie.com/2015/01/27/tab-bar-controllers-in-storyboards/ and others exactly and they just say to drag in the tab bar controller or embed another VC in it and boom - tab bar.

This is what has happened for me:

[image]

The tab bar is grayed out and Im not able to drag a tab bar onto the VC or anywhere. What am I doing wrong here? I need to migrate my standalone VCs into a tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to your relationships between view controllers and view controller 
[this is my tabbarcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZepV.png)

Comment: I understand, you tabbarcontroller have only one tab :) you can select custom image in tab bar item

Comment: But I can't even add other VCs in that relationship the option isn't there

Comment: @skyguy Please select your tabBarControllrer, select -> symbol on right panel and send me screenshot